Why are **differences** in temperatures degrees C or F?
Per what I'm seeing online °F and °C are degrees because they have an arbitrary reference point; however, if you take the difference of two temperatures it's no longer an arbitrary reference. So why is the ° not dropped? Is it just that people are unfamiliar with the degree meaning? An analogy to circle degrees making dropping the unit not done? Or a more formal reason?

Without degree symbols, how shall we say there is a 100-unit difference between water freezing and boiling measured in Centigrade?

Style guides differ on whether to use the degree symbol (as well as whether to have a space before it or the C/F). See this question on writing SE and this blog post.

Please don’t quote opinions from Quora”. Centigrade degrees are units, not reference points, as reference to any scientific source (try Wikipedia) would tell you. And if the height of your brother is 0.9 metre and your height is 0.8 metre, how much taller is your brother than you? 0.1 or 0.1 metre?

The °F and °C are different units of temperature referring to physical things that can be measured (dimensions). K units are the same size as °C but with a different offset (-273.15). Similarly with °R and °F.
The '°F' is the name of the unit. Without the '°' the F would mean farads (units of capacitance). Similarly, C would mean coulombs (units of charge).
Angular degrees (and radians) are a ratio of an angle to a complete circle so they are dimensionless.
There is nothing ambiguous or incorrect in referring to a difference in °C or °F. In the SI Kelvin scale we also use the same symbol (K) as both a unit of absolute temperature and a unit of difference in temperature. In a context where °C is common, sometimes K is used rather than °C to make it more obvious that a temperature difference is intended, but that's more of a convention and optional.
One thing that trips people up occasionally is that conversions are not the same for differences as for temperatures, but the distinction should be obvious from context.
For example, to convert a temperature of 10°C to °F the Celsius temperature is multiplied by 9/5 and 32 added, whereas to to convert a difference of 10°C to °F the number is simply multiplied by 9/5.

It's rather that degree can refer to both a point and an interval on a scale. A temperature or interval of one degree Celsius are both written as 1 °C. It was decided that using 1 °C and 1 C° to distinguish the two would be too confusing and was not adopted. // "One of the divisions or intervals marked on a scale of a measuring instrument." MW // "The water temperature was held at 35.7 ± 0.2 °C" illustrates both uses of degree: a point (temperature) on the Centigrade scale and a range or interval of 0.4 °C.

The C and F scales not only have different reference points, their degrees are of different sizes. One °C is is equivalent to 1.8 °F, when speaking of differences within the scale.
If you are specifying differences in degrees, you must specify which degrees you mean.
If you mean why not use C and F without the degree symbol, you could do that, but including it makes it clear that you are talking about temperatures.

       Perhaps the best way to illustrate the difference between punctive readings on a scale and intervals is to compare with actual times and time intervals:
starting point                                               end point                                               interval                                                                                                                                                                                            2:00pm                                                         8:00pm                                                6 hours  / 6h                                                                                                                                                                                           2°C / 2K                                                         8°C / 8K                                    6 degrees C / 6 degrees K                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Note that 'time' is used both for the actual time (point in time) and duration of interval, but 'temperature' is used only for the point reading. Intervals are 'temperature differences'.
                     With temperatures, the degree symbol / clitic    °    is used, while the expanded 'degrees' is usually preferred for temperature differences / changes.
        Tradition governs the retention of the degree symbol; scientific standardisation recognises that units of temperature are best treated as all other units, so 2K not 2°K. Idiosyncrasies are not uncommon with units. Why £3 /$3 and not 3£ / 3$? Why 3'6"? Why sixteen hundred hours?
